# IQueryable.Where.ToList VS IQueryable.ToList.Where, which query is better in terms of performance?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, iqueryable

I'm having two queries, both are producing same result but I wanna know which one is more efficient. Below are the queries, I've written the query clauses only. The inner conditions are same for both the queries.

1. IQueryable().Where().ToList();
2. IQueryable().ToList().Where();

At my end I've tried below code and it's showing "IQueryable().ToList().Where();" is better. There are few questions that I don't understand:
1. Without seeing my below temporary code what which query is more efficient?
2. As fas as I know, IQueryable is good for querying remote data. So, should not be it better first to filter out the items and then use ToList so that we don't need to perform ToList  function on non relevant items? (if this is the case then why below code is saying query 2 is more efficient?)

```
Stopwatch st1 = new Stopwatch();
Stopwatch st2 = new Stopwatch();
int counter = 10000;
IEnumerable<Employee> iEmp = null;
IQueryable<Employee> qEmp = null;
BindingList<Employee> bList = new BindingList<Employee>();
for (int i = 1; i <= counter; ++i)
{
    bList.Add(new Employee
    {
        Department = $"Dept - {i}",
        EmployeeID = i,
        EmployeeName = $"Employee - {i}",
        Salary = i + 10000
    });
}

iEmp = bList.AsEnumerable<Employee>();
qEmp = bList.AsQueryable<Employee>();

st1.Start();
var t = qEmp.Where(x => x.EmployeeID % 2 == 0).ToList();
st1.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Queryable-Where-ToList: {st1.ElapsedTicks}");

st2.Start();
var t1 = qEmp.ToList().Where(x => x.EmployeeID % 2 == 0);
st2.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Queryable-ToList-Where: {st2.ElapsedTicks}");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Which is faster? Try it out and see! http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @DavidG I don't know if you looked at the code, but he is already using stopwatch to see for himself.

Comment: `ToList` creates a list in memory and fills it. If you use `Where` afterwards you have created this list for no reason. Because it's not referenced anymore it is ready to be garbaged collected. So always use `Where(...).ToList()` (if you need a list at all). If you want to force `Linq-To-Objects` you should use `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList`.

Comment: So `IQueryable` is based on `Expression<T>` and is used against the database (generally speaking). So are you asking if you compile a where expression and execute is it faster than asking for all the items back and apply the where in memory? Because those two things can't be equated

Comment: @EpicKip The question asked is "which query is better in terms of performance?". If OP knows the answer, then they are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @DavidG "Try it out and see!" He did, result was not as expected and asked for clarification. Not a great question as it stands but he did test it.

Comment: @EpicKip Exactly! That's why I'm saying the question should be something else, perhaps "why is one faster then the other?"

Comment: @EpicKip the reason behind my question title is the test I performed was with some dummy data and the question I asked is for Entity framework.

Comment: @sunil20000 with entity framework you **must** do `Where` first.

Comment: @sunil20000 If you want to know how the code behaves when using EF then *test it using EF*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `IQueryable.Where.ToList`. That way the filtering will happen in the context of the query, not collect the results first and filter all the results in memory like how `IQueryable.ToList.Where` would.

In your example with the `BindingList`, it won't matter that much, but it *does* matter when using something like [Entity Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework).

In the case of EF, given

```
Id | Name
1  | Daniel
2  | Miranda
3  | Elianna
```

Doing `.ToList` will give all 3 records back first. Doing `Where` then works with those objects in memory.

```
 var list = query.ToList();
 list.Count == 3; // true
 list.Where(i => i.Id % 2 == 0); // Returns only Miranda
```

However with `.Where` first, it converts it into SQL (pseudo SQL here) then collects the results.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Id % 2 = 0
```

In C#:

```
 var list = query.Where(i => i.Id % 2 == 0).ToList();
 list.Count == 1; // true, only Miranda
```

In the case of why 2 is quicker, your test is flawed. These tests aren't running in isolation. They operate on the same data in a short time which could lead to the CPU/runtime/operating system optimizing some things for you.

Comment: @user4566715 there's plenty of examples on how to benchmark code.

Answer (score 1):

When calling `ToList` you will get all the items into the memory. When you filter on the results of this using a `Where`-statement all this filtering will happen on the client-side (so to speak), that is in memory in your case. However when you use the first approach with `Where`-statement *before* the call to `ToList` the filtering happens on the database-side and as thus should be far faster.

It is not clear why the versa approach would be faster, but from my point you should use the `IQueryable` as long as you can and get the results into memory (which effectivly makes it an `IEnumerable`) when you´re done with the query.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, with your test code IQueryable().ToList().Where() works faster because of implementation of AsQueryable, ToList and Where. AsQueryable just wraps BindingList which is ICollection, and ToList works faster with ICollection than with IEnumerable returned by Where.

In general case IQueryable should be used to build queries to data storage, thus it should be much more effective to execute entire query on DB side (except very rare cases).